# How to make httplib debugger infomation into logger debug level

Tags: python, urllib, httplib

By default httplib debug send, headers and reply information returns as logger.info,

Instead can how do i display send, headers and replay as part of Debug information?

```
import requests
import logging
import httplib
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

logging.basicConfig() # you need to initialize logging, otherwise you will not see anything from requests
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

requests.get('http://httpbin.org/headers')
```

It prints

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP Connection (1):
httpbin.org
send: 'GET /headers HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nA
ccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.8.
1\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: nginx
header: Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2015 12:50:44 GMT
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Content-Length: 156
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
header: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /headers HTTP/1.1" 200 156
<Response [200]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Eli

I could achieve using this post http://stefaanlippens.net/redirect_python_print

```
import logging
import sys
import requests
import httplib


# HTTP stream handler
class WritableObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []
    def write(self, string):
        self.content.append(string)

# A writable object
http_log = WritableObject() 
# Redirection
sys.stdout = http_log 

# Enable 
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 2

# get operation
requests.get('http://httpbin.org/headers')

# Remember to reset sys.stdout!
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__  
debug_info = ''.join(http_log.content).replace('\\r', '').decode('string_escape').replace('\'', '')

# Remove empty lines
debug_info = "\n".join([ll.rstrip() for ll in debug_info.splitlines() if ll.strip()])
```

It prints like

```
C:\Users\vkosuri\Dropbox\robot\lab>python New-Redirect_Stdout.py
send: GET /headers HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.8.1
reply: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
header: Server: nginx
header: Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 09:36:36 GMT
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Content-Length: 156
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
header: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Thanks

Malli

Answer (score 1):

`some_logger.set_level()` does not do what you think it does. It doesn't set the level of the logs being emitted by a logger. It sets the minimum level of log emitted by the logger that your handler will care about and acknowledge. To do what you're asking, I can only think of one real, reasonable way:

Capture the logs as they're coming in and re-log them. You can capture them with the idea described [here](http://alanwsmith.com/capturing-python-log-output-in-a-variable), and use that in a subclass of requests. This would without a doubt be complicated. So, this is probably a good time to start asking yourself, "what am I really trying to achieve and is there another way to go about it?"